# How to pass keys to ListViewBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, key

I have a class containing elements

```
MyClass(key: ValueKey("1")),
```

I would like to display them on the screen in the amount I need. I tried to do this through ListViewBuilder , but I don't quite understand how I can specify the keys inside the ListView that distinguish my class elements

```
ListView.builder(
             itemCount: 5,
             itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return MyClass(key: ValueKey(""));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`itemBuilder` builds element of list one by one. index is number of element is building right now (beginning from 0).

this should work for you

```
ListView.builder(
             itemCount: 5,
             itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return MyClass(key: ValueKey(index.toString()));
```

or if you start from 1

```
 ListView.builder(
                 itemCount: 5,
                 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return MyClass(key: ValueKey((index+1).toString()));
```

Comment: I tried it, but the console gives this error and the content is displayed incorrectly

"Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget."

Comment: You should show more code. This error normally shows when you add listview in column or column in column etc.

Comment: I will update my question by adding more code, but I don't use rows or columns.